# Getting Form data in Spring REST controller - alternatives

Tags: java, spring, forms, rest, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring rest controller and I want to properly receive a form-data from my UI. Do you know any other way of getting form-data besides of my proposal?

I have managed to get the data using @RequestPart("*fields-name*") but its not optimal since I need to get the form-data and send it as it is to another rest controller.

```
MyResponse addAttachment(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("note") String note);
```

In the end I want the flow to look like this:

|UI|--(form-data)---> |Java-Spring A| ---(form-data)----> |Java-Spring B|--(file-from-form)--> |DB|

currently it looks like that:

In spring A: `myResponse addAttachment(@ModelAttribute AttachmentForm form)`

In spring B: `myResponse addAttachment(@ModelAttribute MultiValueMap<String, Object> form)`

From A->B I do the following:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> valueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
valueMap.add("note", form.getNote());
valueMap.add("file_name", file.getOriginalFilename()); //Send the file as bytes array
valueMap.add("files", new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes())); 
resttemplate.sendhttpcall(valueMap);// helper function to send between A->B
```

After sending the form data ( as a model object AttachmentForm) I parse it before sending it from A to B. one step after restTemplate.exchange it gets to Spring B and I get the following exception (in my Expception controller class): 
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap"

Thanks